# OCMock3 Integration Issue with IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, unit-testing, ocmock

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvIlu.png)

I added `OCMock` framework in my project and I wasn't able to take test Success or fail and code coverage.

I got Error like "**Error Generating Code Coverage**"

Anybody knows `OCMock` Integration with steps please help in this.

I tried alot for Integration with `OCMock`.

Thanks in advance!!!

This is the code that I have tried:

```
id obj = OCMClassMock([NSString class]); 
[obj length]; 
[[obj reject] length];
```

I followed the tutorials at the following links:

http://ocmock.org/ios/

http://iosunittesting.com/adding-ocmock-to-a-project/

Comment: Please add the code that you are trying so that others can see what you have tried

Comment: @ Adam Richardson : Not even run the test class Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who one helped here.

Error :

1. Adding Library
2. Adding framework

Resolution 
**pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.4'**

Pod Installation only resolves my problem.